# Why does PHP's foreach advance the pointer of its array (only) once?

Tags: php

This is a question of curiosity about the reasons behind the way `foreach` is implemented within PHP.

Consider:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
foreach ($arr as $x) echo current($arr) . PHP_EOL;
```

which will output:

```
2
2
2
```

I understand that `foreach` rewinds array pointers to the beginning; however, why does it then increment it only once? What is happening inside the magic box?? Is this just an (ugly) artefact?

---

Thanks @NickC -- for anyone else curious about `zval` and `refcount`, you can read up on the basics [here](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php)

Comment: How does that code even work? $arr doesn't look like it's defined anywhere.

Comment: Whats with the echo current($arr)? You are not using $arr in the foreach loop. foreach($arr as $x) echo current($arr).PHP_EOL;

Comment: Ha -- yes I was trying to optimize my loop for pretty-ness sake, but then took out a critical piece!

Comment: `foreach` operates on a copy of the array. I'm not sure why it alters the array pointer at all actually.

Comment: @Boann, yes it almost seems like something is unoptimised (or maybe hyper optimised with hacks) in the core

Comment: @Boann could you point us to the documentation, which explains that foreach operates on array copies? I don't think so.

Comment: I'd expected it to produce `1 1 1` as i thought it would operate on a copy. But then i reread http://de.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php and [http://nikic.github.com/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html](http://nikic.github.com/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html) but than the output should have been `1 2 3` or `1 1 1` but not `2 2 2`. Very nice question!

Comment: @edorian: Yes, an interesting question! I tend to think it is a bug, but I may be wrong. Do you have any clues why this is happening?

Comment: @Tadeck The answer from NikiC seems fine to me

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The linked question is `"I did array stuff inside foreach and everything breaks?!? make it go away"` and this is `"I want a technical explanation of the inner workings of PHP regarding foreach loop behavior"`

Comment: @edorian: Agreed. It seemed to be a duplicate, but indeed it is a more interesting question, a lot cleaner, aimed at getting clarification instead of getting working solution.

Comment: @edorian: Actually it's asking for a technical explanation of undefined behaviour. Doesn't make it less interesting though. The suggested link wasn't the best obviously (surprising hurry with closevotes today); we had a better previous discussion about it [somewhere...](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20foreach%20array%20pointer) - Not that it needs more explanation anymore.

Comment: Interestingly, although the question focus on `foreach`, it seems the answer relies in `current` function behaviour!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Right before the first iteration the `$array` is "soft copied" for use in `foreach`. This means that no actual copy is done, but only the `refcount` of the zval of `$array` is increased to `2`.

On the first iteration:

1. The value is fetched into `$x`.
2. The internal array pointer is moved to the next element, i.e. now points to `2`.
3. `current` is called with `$array` passed by reference. Due to the reference PHP cannot share the `zval` with the loop anymore and it needs to be separated ("hard copied").

On the following iterations the `$array` zval thus isn't anymore related the the `foreach` zval anymore. Thus its array pointer isn't modified anymore and `current` always returns the same element.

By the way, I have written a small summary on [foreach copying behavior](http://nikic.github.com/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html). It might be of interest in the context, but it does not directly relate to the issue as it talks mostly about hard copying.

Comment: On first iteration: reset + next. That's documented. But tried to fool that by iteration by ref and using reset() inside the loop but was not able to. I guess it's a protection against that.

Comment: @MarkTomlin It wouldn't because foreach would then just treat it as an expression instead of a variable. I'm not exactly sure why hakre added it to the answer though.

Comment: I think the `refcount` is actually increased to 3 because of $arr inside the `foreach`-head (`foreach ($arr ...`.

Comment: @PhilippeGerber Yes, debug_zval_dump in the loop (before current) gives refcount 4, so it must be 3 after the start of the loop. Do you know where the additional reference comes from? I only found one ADDREF in FE_RESET

Comment: @NikiC I get a refcount of 3 before the `current()`. I'm don't know the PHP source, but my guess would be: 1. original $arr declaration 2. $arr in the foreach()-head 3. $arr in the foreach()-body. :S

Comment: @PhilippeGerber Just checked and it looks like the refcount decreased from 5.3 to 5.4. 5.3 had a refcount(3) and 5.4 has refcount(2). (You always need to -1 the debug_zval_dump refcount due to the function call.)

Comment: Good to know, thx! Was already wondering whether function parameters have their own symbol (separated from the one used in the function body)...

Comment: I think you can narrow the quest for that unexpected/undefined behaviour down to changes between PHP 5.2.2 and 5.2.4 - Might have something to do with all the references about `Fixed bug #41372 (Internal pointer of source array resets during array copying).` - Before that all versions returned `1 1 1` for OPs example.

Comment: @NikiC Thanks. One followup: why would the internal array pointer get moved (step 2 in your answer)? Is this a by-product of fetching the value into $x?

Comment: @NikiC, in the first paragraph, you said the refcount is increased to 2. But my tests show a refcount of 3. Why is it so? See http://stackoverflow.com/q/18158487/632951

Answer (score 3):

See how interesting, if we change the code just a little bit:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
foreach ($arr as &$x) echo current($arr) . PHP_EOL;
```

We got this output:

```
2
3
```

Some interesting references:

http://nikic.github.com/2011/11/11/PHP-Internals-When-does-foreach-copy.html

http://blog.golemon.com/2007/01/youre-being-lied-to.html

Now, try this:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
foreach ($arr as $x) { $arr2 = $arr; echo current($arr2) . PHP_EOL; }
```

Output:

```
2
3
1
```

This is very curious indeed.

And what about this:

```
$arr = array(1,2,3);
foreach ($arr as $x) { $arr2 = $arr; echo current($arr) . ' / ' . current($arr2) . PHP_EOL; }
echo PHP_EOL;
foreach ($arr as $x) { $arr2 = $arr; echo current($arr2) . ' / ' . current($arr2) . PHP_EOL; }
```

Output:

```
2 / 2
2 / 2
2 / 2

2 / 2
3 / 3
1 / 1
```

It seems what happens is just as written in NickC answer, **plus** the fact that when passing an array as an argument to `current` function, as it is passed *by reference*, something inside there does modify the array passed as argument to it...

Answer (score 1):

This is the results of your code opcode analysis with php 5.3.

See this example : http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.fe-reset.php

number of ops:  15
compiled vars:  !0 = $arr, !1 = $x

```
line     # *  op                           fetch          ext  return  operands
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   2     0  >   INIT_ARRAY                                       ~0      1
   1      ADD_ARRAY_ELEMENT                                ~0      2
   2      ADD_ARRAY_ELEMENT                                ~0      3
   3      ASSIGN                                                   !0, ~0
   3     4    > FE_RESET                                   $2      !0, ->13
   5  > > FE_FETCH                                         $3      $2, ->13
   6  >   ZEND_OP_DATA                                             
   7      ASSIGN                                                   !1, $3
   8      SEND_REF                                                 !0
   9      DO_FCALL                                      1          'current'
  10      CONCAT                                           ~6      $5, '%0A'
  11      ECHO                                                     ~6
  12    > JMP                                                      ->5
  13  >   SWITCH_FREE                                              $2
  14    > RETURN                                                   1
```

See NikiC's answer for details, but you see at line #8 that !0 never change in the loop.(5-12)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't answer the question, but you can use a workaround using `\ArrayIterator`

```php
$arr = new ArrayIterator(array(1,2,3));
foreach ($arr as $x) echo $arr->current() . PHP_EOL;
```

```
1
2
3
```

You can even use `Iterator.next()` to advance the iteration.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question, which was about mechanisms underlying the specific behavior and not about how to get a different answer.

Comment: @JaredSmith Granted. But people might come here looking for ways to use `\current()` or `\next()` while iterating - I know, because I did. For the sake of help for those users, I posted the answer.

Comment: That's totally fair, and I didn't downvote your answer or anything (although it looks like someone else did) because I agree it adds value, but you may want to point out your motivation for posting it even though it doesn't strictly speaking answer the question.