# Why does current() skip over first array element in a foreach() statement?

Tags: php, foreach

This code outputs: 1 1 1 1

I expected either 0 0 0 0 or 0 1 2 3

```
<?php 
$arr = array(0,1,2,3);
foreach($arr as $i)
{
    echo current($arr), ' ';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possible dup of: [Why does PHP's foreach advance the pointer of its array (only) once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263293/why-does-phps-foreach-advance-the-pointer-of-its-array-only-once)

Right after initializing your array, you'll notice that the current index is `0`.

```
$arr = array(0,1,2,3);
echo current($arr); // outputs 0
```

When you enter into your foreach, it increments the internal array pointer by 1, making the "current" value `1`.

Notice how the array is passed to the `current()` function by *reference* (http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php). This causes the behavior your are experiencing.

If you'd like to get the key of the array, you could change your foreach to something like:

```
foreach($arr as $key => $i)
{

}
```

Comment: Oh ya, this is a dup, what should I do about it?