# Unexpected behaviour of current() in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

Here is a simple loop

```
$list = array("A", "B", "C","D");
foreach ($list as $var) {
    print(current($list));
}
```

Output ([demo](http://3v4l.org/sBDjl))

```
 BBBB   // Output for 5.2.4 - 5.5.0alpha4
 BCD    // Output for 4.4.1
 AAAA   // Output for 4.3.0 - 4.4.0, 4.4.2 - 5.2.3
```

Question :

- Can someone please explain whats going on ?
- Why am i not getting ABCD
- Even if a copy of the array was made by `foreach` i should be getting `AAAA` but not getting that in the current `PHP` stable version

Note* I know i can simply use `print $var` but the from PHP DOC

> current — Return the current element in an array
>   The [current()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php) function simply returns the value of the array element that's currently being pointed to by the internal pointer. It does not move the pointer in any way. If the internal pointer points beyond the end of the elements list or the array is empty, current() returns FALSE.

**Update 1 - New Observation**

Thanks to [**Daniel Figueroa**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14849560/1226894) : Just by wrapping `current` in a function you get different result

```
foreach ( $list as $var ) {
    print(item($list));
}

function item($list) {
    return current($list);
}
```

Output ( [Demo](http://3v4l.org/AvLRc) )

```
 BCDA   // What the hell
```

Question :

- Why not getting "BBBB" ?
- How does wrapping current in a function affect `foreach` output ?
- Where did the extra "A" Come from ?

**Update 2**

```
$list = array("A","B","C","D");
item2($list);
function item2($list) {
    foreach ( $list as $var ) {
        print(current($list));
    }
}
```

Output ( [See Demo](http://3v4l.org/1aUpd) )

```
AAAA // No longer BBBB when using a function
```

Question :

- What is the different running a loop in a function and running it outside a function because you get `AAAA` outside and `BBBB` in a function in most PHP version

Comment: you need also next($list) :)

Comment: This must have something to do with 'how foreach works'... it is a mystery :(. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10057671/how-foreach-actually-works)

Comment: Actually... how about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8263293/why-does-phps-foreach-advance-the-pointer-of-its-array-only-once ?

Comment: I've added `arrays` and `foreach` tags too because, IMO, it belongs to it. If you disagree revert my changes. :)

Comment: The title is a bit misleading; there's no errors :)

Comment: What better title do you suggest ?

Comment: This question with all of its content should be added on http://www.phpwtf.org/. Anyway, morale of this question is: `Even if you are 100% sure what the flow of your script will be check it before start implementing in real app. It's php so who knows...`

Comment: See also this answer on another question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14854568/385378

Answer (score 21, accepted):

**Why does it start with B?**

Since 5.2 `foreach` (reliably) advances the array pointer *before* the loop body starts. See also the [`FE_RESET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.fe-reset.php) opcode.

```
$list = array("A", "B", "C","D");
foreach ($list as $var) {
    break;
}
var_dump(current($list));
```

Output:

```
B
```

This may have something to with how the `ZEND_OP_DATA` pseudo opcode works (which isn't really documented).

**Why does `current()` keep giving the same value?**

Before the loop starts, `foreach` creates an internal reference to the array that you're looping over. Once inside the loop, whenever the array variable is modified or passed by reference, the internal reference is disassociated from the variable by making a copy of the array structure (but not the elements). This copied value retains the array pointer (which had earlier been modified by the loop initialization).

This behaviour is also exhibited with a more destructive `unset()` operation:

```
$list = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
  echo $val;
  unset($list[1], $list[2], $list[3]);
}
echo "\n", print_r($list, true), "\n";
```

Output:

```
ABCD
Array
(
    [0] => A
)
```

**Passing loop variable to a function**

This is another interesting scenario:

```
$list = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
function itm($arr) 
{
    return current($arr);
}

foreach ($list as $item) {
    print itm($list);
}
var_dump(current($list));
```

Output:

```
BCDA
bool(false)
```

This time, the array is passed by value and thus its array structure is copied (not the elements) into the function's `$arr` parameter. Unlike the previous example, there's no disassociation between the loop's internal reference and the `$list` symbol because the copy takes place in the function scope.

*What about the last `"A"`?*

This is by far the most mystifying behaviour of `foreach` and can only be witnessed under these circumstances. In the last loop iteration, the array pointer is *seemingly* rewound to the first item; seemingly because at the end of the loop it obviously points beyond the end of the elements (as you can see from the last line of the output).

This may have something to do with the [`SWITCH_FREE`](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.opcodes.switch-free.php) opcode that's executed at the end of a `foreach`.

**So why does placing `foreach` in a function make it different?**

Observe the following code:

```
function item2($arr) 
{
    foreach ($arr as $var) {
        print(current($arr));
    }
    var_dump(current($arr));
}
$list = array("A","B","C","D");
item2($list);
```

Output:

```
AAAA
string(1) "A"
```

In this case, the internal reference of the `foreach` is initialized with a copy of the array (because it has a refcount > 1) and thus creates an immediate disassociation from the `$arr` symbol.

**Can it get worse?**

Of course! You can get even whackier results when you start using references or nest multiple `foreach` loops on the same variable.

**So how can I get consistent results?**

Use [`Iterators`](http://www.php.net/iterator) or don't rely on getting a consistent value from referencing the array variable during a `foreach` operation.

Comment: +Nice but how does it explain http://stackoverflow.com/a/14849560/1226894

Comment: What i don't understand is why the `rewind` came from ? does it mean functions rewinds array ??? or return statement has effect on arrays

Comment: Do you know runing the loop in a function gives  3 different result -http://3v4l.org/1aUpd but Iterators gives same result - http://3v4l.org/ViCNn

Comment: @Baba Yeah, I noticed that as well; iterators are so much more stable :)

Comment: But they can not be used with references ... :(

Comment: @Baba **and** if you think you've seen it all, [think again](http://3v4l.org/EXsLW#v510)

Comment: lol ..... `next()` was called automatically .... One needs to be very careful ..... lol nice one

Comment: what will happen if you call current($any_other_array); inside foreach? I think if you test it you will change your mind!

Comment: @Akam Not sure what you mean; look at [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jZumr7).

Comment: @Baba I'll work on this tonight to confirm my suspicions :)

Comment: @Jack: see my answer, edit: example1 and example2

Comment: @Akam the first two examples can be explained by the function scenario. It's all due to ref counting.

Answer (score 3):

FROM [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)

> The current() function simply returns the value of the array element
>   that's currently being pointed to by the internal pointer. It does not
>   move the pointer in any way

then: use [next()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php)

```
$list = array("A", "B", "C","D");
foreach ($list as $var) {
    print(current($list));
    next($list);
}
```

NOTE: the first element will not be printed because foreach moved the pointer to second element of the array :)

This example will explain the full behaviour:

```
$list = array("A", "B", "C","D");
foreach ($list as $var) {
   if(!isset($a)) reset($list); $a = 'isset';
   print(current($list));
   next($list);
}
```

out put is ABCD

Please also note that:

> ```
> As foreach relies on the internal array pointer changing it within the loop 
> may lead to unexpected behavior.
> ```
>
> [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

---

**EDIT: I want to share also my new confusing finding!!!**

**Example1:**

```
$list = array("A", "B", "C","D");
$list_copy = $list;
foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
  current($list_copy);
  echo current($list);
  //next($list);
}
```

OUTPUT: AAAA

**Example2:**

```
$list = array("A", "B", "C","D");
$list_copy = $list;
foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
  current($list_copy);
  echo current($list);
  next($list);
}
```

OUTPUT: ABCD

**When calling current() function inside foreach even for another array it will affect the foreach behavior...**

**Example3:**

```
$list = array("A", "B", "C","D");

$refcopy = &$list;

foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
  if(!isset($a)) { $a = 'isset'; reset($list); }
  echo current($list);
  next($list);
}
```

OUTPUT: ACD (WOW! **B** is missing)

**Example: 4**

```
$list = array("A", "B", "C","D");

$refcopy = &$list;

foreach ($list as $key => $val) {
  echo current($list);
  next($list);
}
```

OUTPUT: BCD

It can't be decided exactly what will happen inside foreach loop!!!

Answer (score 2):

Well I have no real clue as to why this is, but i suspect it might have something to do with how the assignment is evaluated/processed. For fun I tried this and it resulted in another `incorrect` behaviour:

```
$arr = array('A', 'B', 'C', 'D');
function itm($val) {
    return current($val);
}

foreach ($arr as $item) {
    print itm($arr);
}
```

Result: BCDA

So my guess is that whats happening here is that the function call forces the evaluation of current to happen in a ~correct manner. Also the reason for me getting BCDA instead of ABCD is probably because the internal pointer at first is incremented (pointing at B) and then in the en it is reset back to point at A.

It might be worth noting this line in the [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php):

> Note that the assignment copies the original variable to the new one (assignment by value), so changes to one will not affect the other. This may also have relevance if you need to copy something like a large array inside a tight loop.

I guess this doesn't really count as an answer but I liked your question and wanted to contribute a little.

Comment: Nice this is getting complex .... nice observation

Comment: Indeed, because the soft-copy argument is kind of void now I think.

Comment: Would add your observation to the question .. this is key ... observation

Comment: @DanielFigueroa I think so too. I've just tried to pass `$arr` by reference and it outputs `BBBB`. http://codepad.viper-7.com/6MxdFr

Answer (score 1):

Even if a copy of the array was made by foreach i should be getting AAAA but not getting that in the current PHP stable version

Since I found no answer to this question here, I'll (try to) explain.

Before the first iteration of `foreach` `$list` is not actually copied. Only [reference counting](http://php.net/manual/en/features.gc.refcounting-basics.php) of `$list` will be increased to 2. So on the first iteration: first value of `$list` will be copied in `$var`, pointer will move to the second element of `$list` and *actual copy* of `$list` will be made. So when you call `current` pointer points to second element but on the second and farther iterations it's never modified because *actual copy* of `$list` exists so `current` always will output the second element.

**Edit:**

I've played with `debug_zval_dump` to understand this really very unexpected behavior with:

```
<pre>

<?php


$list = array("A", "B", "C","D");

echo '<h1>Ref count before entering foreach:</h1><br>';
debug_zval_dump($list); echo '<br><br>';

$i = 0;
echo '<h1>Ref count in foreach:</h1><br>';
foreach ($list as $var) {
    $i++;
    echo '<b>Iteration #'.$i.':</b> ';
    debug_zval_dump($list);
    echo '<br>';
}

$list = array("A", "B", "C","D"); //re-assign array to avoid confusion

echo '<h1>Ref count before entering foreach that calls method "item" and passes array by value:</h1><br>';
debug_zval_dump($list);
$i = 0;
echo '<h1>Ref count in foreach that calls method "item" and passes array by value:</h1><br>';
foreach ( $list as $var ) {
    $i++;
    item($list, $i);
}

function item($list, $i) {
    echo '<b>Iteration #'.$i.':</b> ';
    debug_zval_dump($list);
}

$list = array("A", "B", "C","D"); //re-assign array to avoid confusion

echo '<h1>Ref count before entering foreach that calls method "item" and passes array by reference:</h1><br>';
debug_zval_dump($list);
$i = 0;
echo '<h1>Ref count in foreach that calls method "item" and passes array by reference:</h1><br>';
foreach ( $list as $var ) {
    $i++;
    itemWithRef($list, $i);
}

function itemWithRef(&$list, $i) {
    echo '<b>Iteration #'.$i.':</b> ';
    debug_zval_dump($list);
}
```

And got the following output:

```
Ref count before entering foreach:
array(4) refcount(2){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(1)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(1)
}


Ref count in foreach:
Iteration #1: array(4) refcount(3){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(2)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(1)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(1)
}

Iteration #2: array(4) refcount(3){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(2)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(1)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(1)
}

Iteration #3: array(4) refcount(3){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(2)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(1)
}

Iteration #4: array(4) refcount(3){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(1)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(2)
}

Ref count before entering foreach that calls method "item" and passes array by value:
array(4) refcount(2){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(1)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(1)
}
Ref count in foreach that calls method "item" and passes array by value:
Iteration #1: array(4) refcount(5){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(2)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(1)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(1)
}
Iteration #2: array(4) refcount(5){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(2)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(1)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(1)
}
Iteration #3: array(4) refcount(5){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(2)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(1)
}
Iteration #4: array(4) refcount(5){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(1)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(2)
}
Ref count before entering foreach that calls method "item" and passes array by reference:
array(4) refcount(2){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(1)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(1)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(1)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(1)
}
Ref count in foreach that calls method "item" and passes array by reference:
Iteration #1: array(4) refcount(1){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(4)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(3)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(3)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(3)
}
Iteration #2: array(4) refcount(1){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(3)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(4)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(3)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(3)
}
Iteration #3: array(4) refcount(1){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(3)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(3)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(4)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(3)
}
Iteration #4: array(4) refcount(1){
  [0]=>
  string(1) "A" refcount(3)
  [1]=>
  string(1) "B" refcount(3)
  [2]=>
  string(1) "C" refcount(3)
  [3]=>
  string(1) "D" refcount(4)
}
```

The output is little bit confusing.

In first example `foreach` has created internal copy of `$list` so reference count was 2 (4 in the result because `debug_zval_dump` adds one `refCount`). In the second example (pass by value) `refCount` increased to 3, because `$list` was copied for function. In the third example count kept to 1 because `$list` was passed by value. I need some time to realize why. If you get the point out of this result share.

All I can say is that when we passed array by value `foreach` was passing array that was iterating, but when passed by reference it took the *original* `$list`. The question is: why was `foreach` passing that array?

Comment: + Nice but you need to see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14849560/1226894

Comment: @Baba Yes, I've seen and I am thinking "wtfphp".

Comment: I can't believe it myself

Comment: @Baba Without debugging `zval` we won't be able to understand. Just playing around with it.

Comment: @Baba Edited my answer and so we could see `refCount`.

Comment: @Baba Final edit. What do you think?

Comment: Do you know runing the loop in a function gives  3 different result -http://3v4l.org/1aUpd but Iterators gives same result - http://3v4l.org/ViCNn

Comment: @Baba Did not know that. After this I am much more sure that we should never use these kind of structures in real world apps. It will be huge head-ache later. Behavior is simply undefined.

Comment: I agree but the sad news is that you can not use Iterator with References so we are screwed as DavidRandom would say

Answer (score 1):

The code you use if a lie. Even literally it might look like the same code, however the variables are not (http://3v4l.org/jainJ).

To answer your actual question, for consistent results use the right tools.

If you need a variable with an array value, assign it:

```
$list = array(....);
```

If you need to get the current value of *that* array, use it *before* the `foreach`:

```
$current = current($list);
```

Because inside the `foreach` this might be the same variable name but the value will be different (imagine, you're iterating!).

If you need the *current* value per each iteration, use it:

```
foreach ($list as $current) {
    ...
}
```

See `$current`?

Oh gosh, yeah, it was that easy. Wait I already have consistent results. Oh and it was that easy to not fool myself. Yay! ;)

For the log: Passing a variable as function parameter makes it a new variable. Even when a reference (that is explained).

When in doubt, do not use PHP references. Or not even variables: http://3v4l.org/6p5nZ

Answer (score 0):

Great point out. But it seems memory pointing issue with different version of php.
Also **current** gives only current position which you have not increment(navigated) anywhere so not getting proper output. As different version of php interpreting next and starting point of array in different ways a solution to this could be a **reset** inside the loop with some condition.
(by the way looping and then using current, next prev is not a good way as already have object in var :) what ever it is your choice)
This is one way you can get it work:

```
<?php
$list = array("A", "B", "C","D");
$flag =0;
foreach ($list as $var) {
    if($flag==0)
    {   
        reset($list);
        $flag=1;
    }
    print(current($list));
    next($list);
}
```

Output is ABCD.
See at http://3v4l.org/5Hm5Y

Answer (score -1):

```
$list = array("A", "B", "C","D");
foreach ($list as $var) {
    echo $var;
}
```

Should do it.

Comment: Please review the problem as stated in the question.  The question is about the unusual behavior of `current` inside a foreach, not how to obtain a specific output.

Answer (score -1):

Use This you already know what's happen !

```
$list = array('A', 'B', 'C','D');
foreach ($list as $var) {
 var_dump(current($list));
}
```

may be its help you!